Equivalent ways to define structure sheaf on $Spec(A)$.
How do we show that the following two ways of defining the structure sheaf on $Spec(A)$ are the same?
Definition 1 $$\mathcal{O}(U) = \left\{s \in \prod_{\mathfrak{p} \in U} A_{\mathfrak{p}} : s \text{ is locally consistent}\right\},$$
where "$s$ is locally consistent" is defined by
$$\forall \mathfrak{p} \in U ~ \exists a,f \in A ~ \forall \mathfrak{q} \in U \cap D(f).~ s(\mathfrak{q})=a/f$$
Definition 2
$$\mathcal{O}(U) = \varprojlim_{D(f) \subseteq U}  \, A[f^{-1}].$$

What have you tried?

@Aphelli I have trouble understanding how to switch from disjoint union of $p $ to f.

In the first, I would think you'd want a condition $f \notin \mathfrak{p}$ in the $\exists$ part, so that $\mathfrak{p} \in U\cap D(f)$.
